# How to copy nested object properties using spread operator

Tags: reactjs

I have an array of objects and each object has these values

```
 id: "53ed5e27-23a5-4a06-b53f-d0113d607fb5"
measure:
units: Array(2)
0: {perPortion: 15, name: "tbsp"}
1: {perPortion: 1, name: "ml"}
```

I am looping over the array and passing an on click function to a button.

```
function handleClick(index: number, ingredient: Data) {
    //copy original array
    const newListArr = [...props.data];

    newListArr[index] = {
        ...newListArr[index],
      }
```

}

The function is getting the index of the object clicked. I am copying the looped array and then I am trying to use the spread operator to bring in all the properties.

My problem is that I dont know how to use spread operator with nested objects.

**I want to get only target the value of the "perPortion" key inside the units array without affecting anything else.**
How can i do that ?

Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to get only target the value of the "perPortion" key inside the
> units array without affecting anything else.

You can copy the entire nested object then overwrite values for specific keys. You will need to shallow copy all nested properties that are being updated.

```
function handleClick(index: number, ingredient: Data) {
  const newItem = {
    // shallow copy data
    ...props.data,
    measure: {
      // shallow copy measure object
      ...props.data.measure,
      // copy units array
      units: props.data.measure.units.map((unit, i) =>
        i === index
          ? {
              // shallow copy specific unit at matched index
              ...unit,
              perPortion: // new per portion value
            }
          : unit
      )
    }
  };

  .... // return or use newItem
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Drew, I did that but the key PerPortion is just getting added to the whole object  instead of getting overwritten

Comment: Ideally I would like to target only the "perPortion" key inside the first object  units[0].perPortion

Comment: @Whyudodis That means `perPortion` property doesn't exist in array objects previously, to be overwritten. Can you share an example of your actual data, and what specifically you are trying to update a `perPortion` property of?

Comment: perPortion only exists inside "units" which is an array and "units" exists inside "measure" which is an object. Thank you very much for your time

Comment: @Whyudodis No worries. Can you share what the outer object is? Is it just an object or is it also part of *some* array? Is `index` in the handler the index of the nested `units` array you want to update?

Comment: This is the whole object , please ignore the json format
`  {
    "name": "chili pepper",
 id: "53ed5e27-23a5-4a06-b53f-d0113d607fb5"
    "measure": {
      "units": [
        {
          "perPortion": 1,
          "name": "pieces"
        }
      ]
    }
  }`.     I am trying to connect the perPortion value with a "+" button that will increment the value of perPortion by one